# Meaning of "take care of the dishes"

Tags: translation

Does the sentence "take care of the dishes" mean just cleaning them? There's something more implied? Could it mean cleaning the whole kitchen?

Context: He cooks and takes care of the dishes.

Comment: Just cleaning the dishes. And maybe placing them where they belong.

Comment: Generally, in the US, the phrase "take care of the dishes" refers to removing used eating utensils from a dining area, washing them appropriately, and "putting them away".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Take care of" means "be responsible for".  So it's whatever work is associated with the dishes, and that could be different in different contexts.

If it is before a meal, it could mean setting the table, or even an announcement of an intent to be responsible for the dishes after the meal.

If the context is after the meal, that might include clearing them from the table. If they have a dishwasher, it would mean loading it.  If no dishwasher, it would mean washing them by hand.  If they normally hand dry them, it would include that.  If they allow them to air dry, it would include putting them on a rack to dry.  It would probably include putting them away.

But the context could even be something like purchasing wedding gifts.  A number of people could be coordinating which items each will buy as gifts.  In that context, "I'll take care of the dishes" could mean I'll be responsible for gifting the dishes.

After an earthquake, a house could be littered with fallen and broken items.  In coordinating cleanup activities, someone could use that expression to take responsibility for sorting out and cleaning up the fallen dishes and dish debris in the kitchen.

So the expression means taking responsibility for doing whatever is entailed in dealing with the dishes in the given context.